# It it possible to corrupt external HDDs by cloning big git repositories?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, git, clone

I bought a Seagate Expansion 5TB external hard drive and I started cloning the git repositories I contributed to.

There is a big git repository (~16GB, 1GB is just the `.git` directory): after cloning it on my hard drive the HDD started to be really slow. First I thought it is just a formatting issue.

Thanks to warranty services I got a new HDD, exactly the same model.

Now I repeat the whole process and everything was running smoothly (`~300MB/sec`). Then I cloned this big repository and now all my data on my HDD is potentially lost. I started to copy it from it to my computer but it's very slow (`~18kB/sec`):

[image]

I made sure to take care of the HDD to not break it, but it looks like this repository has the potential to corrupt it.

I'm wondering if it's a hardware issue or not. The guys from warranty service didn't tell me anything about what the problem was. They just sent me a new HDD.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. Here the HDD is working, but it's very slow. On Windows machines it doesn't work at all. The whole file explorer crashes.

How can I solve the issue? Can a git repository corrupt such an HDD?

Why is it so slow only after cloning this specific repository? I did copy lots of GBs of data before and it was fast.

Comment: Writing data to a HDD does not corrupt it.  I routinely copy 16GB and 1GB files between HDDs over USB.

Comment: @Ramhound But why is it so slow now? It was fast before cloning the repository and now it's slow.

Comment: I have no idea.  You didn't ask if why it was slow.  I can only indicate that there is no technical reason for your HDD to become "corrupt" by transferring files to it.  HDDs are designed to be written to.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, I added that to my post.

Comment: What filesystem is the drive formatted? Do you get the speed back if you reformat the disk? What is the sector size of the disk? (Hint: probably 4k sectors) Does it match the sector size used by your filesystem? A mismatch in sector/cluster sizes could be causing a read-modify-write cycle which could incur a performance hit.

Comment: You should check the errors on your external hard drive and let us know if the problem still persists

Comment: @Mokubai It's `ntfs`. Previously, when I reformatted the disk there was no difference. *What is the sector size of the disk?* — How can I find that?

Comment: @ek.bic How can I do that?

Comment: @ntfs on Linux?

Comment: Open windows, plug the drive and open Computer. Then right click to your external hard drive and click properties. Then go to the second or third tab in properties. You should see something like check hard drive for file system errors. Click that and let windows try to fix your external hard drive. Then shutdown your PC and open it again, boot into Windows and plug your hard drive and check its speed by copying some files

Comment: @ek.bic *Then right click to your external hard drive* — That's what I'm saying: after a loooong time (10 minutes?) the hard drive appears in *My Computer*, but by right clicking the entire machine is freezing...

Comment: Erm.. You should check the drive on Linux then.. But I don't know how to do that, you may use GParted

Comment: @ek.bic Already did but it's **extremely** slow that it's probably not worth to waste my time with it. I'm happy because I saved everything that I copied on it, and I just submitted a new ticket for warranty... Not sure how this will end, but hopefully they will find a nice solution as long they are humans, not robots. :)

Comment: Yeah  I think its slow because its trying to fix the errors. Run the fixer for about 4 - 5 hours or run it when you're about to sleep and take a picture of what happened (logs etc..) and give us the picture. Just let it run for some time and lets see the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what operating system you have makes this a bit of a guessing game, but in certain cases and filesystems there is a possibility of a read from the drive causing a simultaneous write to the drive while the system updates the "accessed" time of the file.

If the drive has 4k sectors and your filesystem is using 512-byte sectors then there is a performance hit whenever a small write is done to the other 7 512-byte blocks in that "real" sector. Essentially every time any of those 8 logical (filesystem) sectors has to be changed the drive must first read the entire 4kb block, modify it, and then write it back.

Combine this with the last accessed time and you could end up with a lot of time modifying blocks with pointless accounting data rather than actually reading or writing data.

In Linux you can disable this last accessed time by specifying the `noatime` mount option when mounting the disk.

Example `fstab`:

```
/dev/sda7          /chroot          ext2          defaults,noatime          1  2
```

From http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html

Comment: I did mention in my post that *I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. Here the HDD is working, but it's very slow. On Windows machines it doesn't work at all. The whole file explorer crashes.*

Comment: I added ` UUID=DE3AEFD13AEFA4AD none                                ntfs    defaults,noatime              0       0` to my `/etc/fstab`. I mounted it but `noatime` does not appear in `cat /proc/mounts` output... Should I specify it using `-o defaults,noatime`?

Comment: By running `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/$USER/HDD/ -o defaults,noatime` it did increase the performance to `30-70 MB/sec` which is not bad. Is there anything I can do to make the performance even better? Before it was like `300MB/sec`. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @IonicăBizău apologies, I missed that line in your question.  Specifying `-o defaults,noatime` should work.  As it stands though my answer is only really a guess at what *could* cause a problem.  It's possible that there's a bug in the Linux NTFS module.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Your drive is USB3 and as long as you've plugged it into a USB3 port I can't say for certain why it would be that speed.  Large (GB sized) files *should* transfer at the full speed of the drive, but small files will generally transfer slower.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug since on Windows this HDD is not usable at all (only after this behavior appears). I tried to delete the big repo I was talking about. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/nQKKx8K.png) is the error I'm getting. I feel this is related to the same problem. Do you know how can I solve this error?